# How can we clear the backlog of tag usage guidance and wiki edits?

Tags: discussion, tags

A good number of our tags have pending [suggested edits](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96/how-can-i-edit-tag-wiki-entries), which at this point just means that people have written *usage guidance* and *wiki* entries for the tags. If I'm not mistaken, only people with 750 rep (5000 for non-beta sites) can approve tag wiki edits, so those edits are piling up. And no one can make an edit to a tag that already has an edit pending, which means people who want to contribute to those tags can't do so.

How can we clear this backlog? Do we just have to wait until a sufficient number of people have 750 rep?

Comment: Interestingly, you need less rep to review a tag wiki than to immediately edit one. Robert is the only mod around, so he is the only one who can clear the queue, however, if someone isn't familiar with a SE site can't review this stuff. Let's better wait other members to reach 750 rep and review tag edits. Rep stats [here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/121892.phase=beta&users=reputation#tab-top). Perhaps the one who will reach 750 needs to be pinged in chat to review. If you reach 1500 rep, you can conflict your previous suggested edits

Comment: @double-beep 1500, not 750, right?

Comment: Oh never mind. I see I can review tag edits on main too. So I guess it's 750?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEoVN.png

Comment: Got it. Where can people find that list?

Comment: https://or.stackexchange.com/help/privileges or for meta https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there's not much that can be done until we have more users with 750 reputation (the [approve tag wiki edits privilege](https://or.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits)). It takes 2 users to approve tag wiki edits, and other than the community managers, you are the only one who can review them.

So really, all we can do is either convince the CMs to review more suggested edits or wait for more users with enough rep to review tag wiki suggested edits (which, at the current rate, should not take very long at all) and encourage them to review.

Answer (score 3):

As users continue to gain reputation to perform these tasks, the pro tem moderator team will be either appointed or elected in the upcoming weeks. In the meantime, I can generally resolve issues that are blocking until you have your own moderators. Reviewing the earliest tag wikis immediately upon submission isn't generally considered something needing *immediate* attention, but I approved most of those waiting in the review queue nonetheless.

Comment: OK, thanks. I did not mean to suggest these are emergencies, just noticed that new edits were being "blocked" by the pending ones.