# Connecting tags between Operations Research and Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I just joined the Operation Research Beta and started looking around.

After a while I started setting my tags and noticed that there is no `cvx` tag. I looked for other tags and then looking if they appear in the Stack Overflow tags, and they did.

So my question is, why don't we connect between those tags, maybe add an option to look at the definition in other sites, maybe even merge if the meaning is the same. This is a suggestion for connect between Operation Research and the original tags.

Advantages:

- No "Code Duplication": As programmers we know not to write the same code twice, we should not write the same tag twice.
- More tag information: A user will be able to see his tag from other perspective that might interest him or her.

Disadvantages:

- Too Much Information: I believe this disadvantage can be solved with good UI but the user can feel a bit overwhelmed if the definition has so many links.

To conclude, I do think connecting is the right call. A lot of people including me would like to see what are the different perspective of my tag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I edit tag wiki entries?](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96/how-can-i-edit-tag-wiki-entries)

Comment: **Rarely** tags are a duplicate on more than one site, example: [tag:election], and the Wiki entry ***must*** be identical. More frequently there's some overlap between tags on different sites, that usually accounts for the name being the same, counterexample: Stack Overflow [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), vs Coffee.SE or Travel.SE. Each site must have its tag's Wiki uniquely answer **why** the usage of the tag on one particular site (and a question on said site) would result in an answer that is different than if it were asked on a different site, using the same tag.

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE, and thanks for your question!

Comment: @Rob Thanks, it does help but not exactly the problem I am talking about.

Comment: @Rob I see what you are saying, merge is probably not the right thing to do. What do you think about a way to link the definitions? There are synonyms to tags, we can add a green synonyms if it is coming from another site. I would like to hear your opinion.

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 I would like you to read that too :) Thanks.

Comment: Yonlif, [see **this** example](https://or.stackexchange.com/tags/combinatorics/info). Customized for ***our*** site, tagged ***to*** our site, yet in reality it *was* copied from elsewhere, for the most part; **but** such *copying* is fully attributed (and neither plagiarized nor too lazily copied; they *are* identical to the extent that the meaning is identical (but we might redefine ours)). It is entirely our own version. That's a fairly good example of how to write a Wiki, but not the only way. @Larry?

Comment: Because you wrote this FR on our Meta it suggests that *we* need this feature, that we should convince the Developers to add an extra feature to our site alone, and that other sites couldn't benefit from your idea. **IF** your suggestion were useful to multiple sites you would post it on the [main Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), ***there*** you would find that [it's a *rejected* duplicate request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299479/282094) with 15 upvotes in almost 9 years.  --- To write your FR here you should explain why ***we*** need it above the needs of everyone else; good lu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with the comments by @Rob above. There doesn't seem to be a need, or a precedent, for merging or connecting tags between multiple sites, and moreover it doesn't seem desirable to me. OR.SE will have its own definition of [cvx](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cvx) and SO will have its definition, and that's OK.

It could also open up a big can of worms. OR.SE has some overlap with a lot of other sites -- SO, Math, Math Overflow, CrossValidated, etc. We don't want to have to manage tag-coordination among all of them.